Code Runner not showing "This extension is enabled globally"
I have installed Code Runner in VS code based on coursera, but it doesn't show "This extension is enabled globally" and when I check Output it says that "node is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." I even made the system PATH variable set correctly.

I've set the PATH variable correctly
uninstall then installed several times the extension Code Runner and still no "This extension is enabled globally"

